# War „Gesundheit!“ immer nur ein Wort?

Tags: etymology, interjection

Ein üblicher Spruch nach dem niesen ist „Gesundheit!“. Auf anderen Sprachen gibt es ganze Sätze für diese Absicht:

- Auf Englisch: „Bless you!“
- Auf Schwedisch: „[Prosit!](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prosit#Latin)“ (vom Latein)

Kontextlos ergibt aber „Gesundheit!“ kein Sinn. Deshalb glaube ich, dass es nur eine Verkürzung einer längeren Phrase ist, z.B. „Für deine Gesundheit!“. Wie ist die Herkunft?

Comment: Nicht ganz die Antwort aber vielleicht ein Weg zum Ziel: http://de.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070102052203AAeRGEb

Comment: Fun fact: "In Lateinamerika ergeht bei wiederholtem Niesen eine Kaskade von guten Wünschen: salud („Gesundheit“) beim ersten, dinero („Geld“) beim zweiten und amor („Liebe“) beim dritten Mal." (Wikipedia)

Comment: da scheint ja auch eine interessante Nähe zu Tricksprüchen zu bestehen "Auf die Gesundheit, prost"

Comment: Grimms Wörterbuch kennt es als „zur Gesundheit“. Das taugt aber freilich nur bedingt als Ursprungsangabe.

Answer (score 7):

Ich bin mir sicher, dass "Gesundheit" aus praktischen Gründen immer schon in einem Wort ausgesprochen wurde an Stelle von

> Ich wünsche dir/Ihnen Gesundheit.

Der Grund ist derselbe, warum man eher "Danke!" als "Ich danke dir" und "Entschuldigung!" statt ["Ich bitte um Entschuldigung"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1089/kann-man-sich-entschuldigen-oder-nur-um-entschuldigung-bitten) sagt.

Manche Menschen behaupten, früher habe der Sprechende  "Ich wünsche *mir (selbst)* Gesundheit." gemeint.  Ich persönlich bezweifle aber diese Vermutung.

---

Es gibt übrigens noch weitere äquivalente Ausdrücke:

> Zum Wohl! *(in Österreich)*
>
> Helf Gott! *(Süddeutschland/Österreich)*

und – scherzhaft gemeint – auch

> Zerreißen soll es dich!
>
> Schönheit!

Comment: Scherzhaft wünscht man sich unter Freunden auch manchmal *Schönheit!*. Nach dem Knigge soll sich übrigens seit Neuestem der Niesende bei seinen Mitmenschen entschuldigen, der Gesundheitswunsch durch ebendiese entfällt glaube ich.

Comment: @Deve siehe letzte Zeile :-) Was den Knigge betrifft: Ich verlasse mich lieber auf mein Gefühl und meinen Hausverstand als auf irgendeine Vorschrift. Wofür soll man denn um Entschuldigung bitten (außer man niest ins Buffet)? Niesen ist doch gesund! ;-)

Comment: Übrigens ist das recht ähnlich zu „Herzlichen Glückwunsch“ oder „Alles Gute“; dort würde man ja normalerweise auch sagen „Ich wünsche dir einen herzlichen Glückwunsch/alles Gute […]”, aber verkürzt ist es einfach *normaler*.

Comment: @Deve Finde ich nicht gut. Ich niese manchmal 5mal hintereinander, wie soll ich da reden? Ich vermute sogar, dass die Hauptfunktion von "Gesundheit" ist, die Pause zu überbrücken:

Comment: Ich hab's nur angemerkt. Das heißt nicht, dass ich finde, es müsse sich jeder danach richten.

Comment: @Deve: Diese Regel wurde meines Wissens 2008 wieder abgeschafft. Ich glaube, der Zusammenhang war hier, dass in einigen anderen Kulturen eher eine Entschuldigung des Niesenden üblich ist. Aber die deutsche Kultur ist natürlich keine andere Kultur, daher ist das ja ebenso unsinnig wie die komplette Kleinschreibung zu fordern, *weil alle anderen Sprachen das auch machen*. Aber Knigge, ich meine, wer vorschreibt, dass Spargel mit dem Kopf nach links serviert werden soll, weil man dem Gast ja das beste zuerst anbieten muss, aber dabei Genießer wie mich (das beste zuletzt!) außer Acht lässt...