# Kann man sich entschuldigen oder nur um Entschuldigung bitten?

Tags: expression

*Achtung: Folgende Frage könnte als Haarspalterei oder Spitzfindigkeit empfunden werden.*

---

Ich frage mich, ob der folgende Ausdruck

> sich entschuldigen

eigentlich richtig ist. Man hört ihn sehr häufig, und jeder versteht ihn. Mein Problem damit ist ein inhaltliches: Jemand entschuldigt sich *selbst*, sprich er **befreit sich selbst** von der Schuld.

Sollte es nicht immer

> Ich bitte um Entschuldigung.

oder

> Ich bitte um Verzeihung.

heißen? D. h., der bereuende Mensch kann nur bitten – entschuldigen oder verzeihen müssen aber andere?

Comment: "ich entschuldige mich" ist fast so schlimm wie "Wir danken für Ihr Verständnis."

Comment: Ich denke, man sollte hier unterscheiden zwischen "Was ist guter Stil?" und "Was ist richtig?". Wie @RegDwight schreibt, ist beides richtig - aber besserer Stil ist meiner Meinung nach *ich bitte um Entschuldigung*. Je nach Situation mag das aber etwas gestelzt oder affektiert wirken.

Comment: _Es tut mir leid_, wenn der erste Satz deiner Frage, mich zu zu einer _haarspaltende_ Frage über _Haarspalterei_ verleitet hat.

Comment: Meines Erachtens nach ist dies abgeschliffener Sprachgebrauch wie im Fall von "komisch", welches oft auch für "seltsam" oder "merkwürdig" gebraucht wird. Wobei "merkwürdig" in der Bedeutung "seltsam" wiederum seltsam einseitig klingt. Berechtigte Frage und ich schließe mich @musiKk an.

Comment: Mir bleibt ein "Ich entschuldige mich" immer quer im Gehörgang stecken, wenn ich es höre :-( Hierzu ein Artikel vom 02.12.2013, der mir aus der Seele spricht: http://www.welt.de/kultur/literarischewelt/article122447817/Kein-Mensch-kann-sich-entschuldigen.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Natürlich kann man sich entschuldigen. Unzählige Muttersprachler tun das jeden Tag und werden von unzähligen anderen Muttersprachlern richtig verstanden.

Das Verb *entschuldigen* hat nun mal zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen:

1. von Schuld freisprechen
2. um Vergebung bitten

Zum einen ist das an sich nichts Ungewöhnliches. Das Wort *Läufer* z. B. hat zig verschiedene Bedeutungen. Um die Wikipedia kurz zu [zitieren](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemie),

> Die meisten Wörter sind polysem, beschreiben also mehrere mehr oder minder unterschiedliche Sachverhalte, die sich aus einem gemeinsamen Kontext entwickeln. Polysemie gilt als natürlichsprachlicher Normalfall und als Ausdruck des sprachlichen Ökonomie-Prinzips.

Zum anderen aber, was noch wichtiger ist: Die beiden *Bedeutungen* des Verbes sind auch *grammatikalisch* klar voneinander getrennt. In der Bedeutung 1 ist es transitiv, aber nicht reflexiv; in der Bedeutung 2 ist es reflexiv, aber nicht transitiv.

„Ich entschuldige Dich“ (transitiv) würde niemals als „Ich bitte für Dich um Vergebung“ missverstanden werden. Genauso wirst Du „Ich entschuldige mich“ (reflexiv) niemals als „Ich spreche mich selbst von jedweder Schuld frei“ missverstehen – außer Du legst es ganz gezielt darauf an, dem Sprecher Mehrdeutigkeit zu unterstellen, wo gar keine vorliegt. Auf Neudeutsch nennt man das wohl Trolling.

Wenn ich hingegen von einem Läufer spreche, hast Du *grammatikalisch* überhaupt keine Anhaltspunkte, ob ich damit Usain Bolt meine oder den Teppich, auf dem er übt. Oder den Teil eines Elektromotors, an den er dabei denkt. Oder die Schachfigur, die er dabei in der Hand hält. Oder, oder, oder. Einfach furchtbar! Wer also an Haarspalterei und Spitzfindigkeit Gefallen findet, sollte viel lieber an dieser Stelle ansetzen.

Comment: Es gibt natürlich schon Sprecher, die es darauf anlegen. (Jörg Haider: ...wenn Sie unbedingt meinen sich beleidigt fühlen zu müssen, 
dann kann ich mich meinetwegen auch entschuldigen...)

Comment: @thei: klare Sache; man kann es auch als Sprecher darauf anlegen, nicht nur als Zuhörer. Das ist aber, wie gesagt, *bei anderen Wörtern nicht anders*. Ich kann mit voller Absicht eine Bekannte als "Freundin" bezeichnen, damit die Leute denken, wir seien zusammen. Das heißt aber noch lange nicht, daß "Freundin" genau eine "korrekte" Bedeutung hat, und alle anderen Bedeutungen "inkorrekt" oder "unlogisch" oder wasweißich sind. (^_^)

Comment: @RedDwight: Dein letzter Absatz ist aber tatsächlich falsch. "Ich kann heute nicht zum Training kommen". "Kein Problem, ich entschuldige dich."

Comment: @thei: "Kein Problem, ich entschuldige dich" lese ich als "Du bist hiermit entschuldigt" (Lehrer), und nicht als "Ich werde für Dich um Entschuldigung bitten" (Mitschüler). Also Bedeutung 1.

Comment: @RegDwight: Nein, das würde ich wirklich zu einem Mitspieler sagen, den ich dann beim Trainer entschuldige.

Comment: Ich bin eigentlich geneigt, es so zu sehen wie der Fragesteller, aber Deine Antwort überzeugt mich. Dennoch finde ich es sprachlich schön (wenn auch vielleicht etwas gestelzt), explizit um Entschuldigung zu bitten - vielleicht nicht bei jeder Kleinigkeit, wenn es eh nur eine Floskel ist, aber bei groben Fehltritten durchaus. Ich finde, das wirkt etwas demütig. Und so gehört es sich auch.

Comment: @fzwo: absolut. Gerade bei Entschuldigungen ist es ist sicherlich nicht verkehrt, eine etwas gehobenere Ausdrucksweise zu wählen. Das ist aber eine Frage des Stils, nicht der Grammatik. *Grammatikalisch* gesehen ist "ich bitte vielmals um Verzeihung" kein bißchen korrekter als "Tschuldigung".

Comment: Zum Beitrag: "Natürlich kann man sich entschuldigen. Unzählige Muttersprachler tun das jeden Tag und werden von unzähligen anderen Muttersprachlern richtig verstanden."
Das sehe ich anders: In zwei führenden europäischen Sprachen wird grundsätzlich nur um Entschuldigung gebeten.
Englisch: "Excuse me please!" oder "Beg your pardon!"
Französisch:>>excuse-moi<< oder >>pardonnez moi<<

Comment: @Charly: um, wir reden hier über Deutsch. Deutsche Muttersprachler. In Deutsch. Französisch oder Englisch tun hier nichts zur Sache. Und sowas wie "führende Sprachen" gibt es nicht. Jede Sprache steht für sich und hat ihre ganz eigene Grammatik. Einfachstes Beispiel: Milliarden von Menschen benutzen in ihren Muttersprachen keine Artikel. Dein Argument ist nun, daß wir im Deutschen auch keine Artikel benutzen dürfen. Viel Erfolg damit.

Comment: Im übrigen ist Dein Widerspruch schon von der Struktur her keiner. Ich sage: "Millionen Katzen sind schwarz". Du sagst, "das sehe ich anders; viele führende Katzen sind weiß". Das ist kein Widerspruch. Meine Aussage bezieht sich ausdrücklich nicht auf alle Katzen, sondern nur auf Millionen davon. Die anderen können weiß, grau, orange oder durchsichtig sein. Das ändert nichts daran, daß die Millionen schwarzer Katzen nach wie vor schwarz sind. Da kannst Du gar nicht sagen, "ich sehe das anders". Auch Du siehst ganz klar mit Deinen eigenen Augen, daß die schwarzen Katzen schwarz sind.

Comment: Und zu guter Letzt hinkt Deine Übersetzung. Weder "beg your pardon" im Englischen noch "excusez-moi" oder "pardonnez-moi" im Französischen bedeuten "ich entschuldige mich". Ins Deutsche werden sie eben als "entschuldigen Sie mich" übersetzt. "Ich entschuldige mich" kann nicht als "I beg your pardon" übersetzt werden, das ergibt gar keinen Sinn. Man würde stattdessen "I apologize" sagen. Und im Russischen z. B. sagt man wörtlich "ich entschuldigemich" (also ebenfalls reflexiv) oder gar "ich entschuldige" (was weder im Deutschen noch im Englischen oder Französischzen Sinn ergibt).

Comment: Gibt es einen Beleg für die zwei Bedeutungen? Oder ist das einfach nur unterschiedlicher (und möglicherweise einmal falscher) Sprachgebrauch?

Answer (score 8):

Ich kann nur für mich sprechen – und zustimmen. Ich würde nicht so weit gehen, zu sagen, dass eine Form *falsch* ist, aber am liebsten höre ich

> Ich bitte um Entschuldigung.

Eine noch annehmbare Version ist

> Ich möchte mich entschuldigen.

Gar nicht gern höre ich

> Ich entschuldige mich.

Comment: Die Seite sollte allgemeingültige Antworten geben, keine persönlichen Befindlichkeiten breitwalzen.

Answer (score 6):

Ich stimme der emotionalen Einschätzung zwar zu, möchte aber explizit darauf hinweisen, dass

> Ich entschuldige mich.

dennoch korrekter und üblicher Sprachgebrauch ist.

Comment: Nur, weil etwas üblicherweise gebraucht wird, ist es noch lange nicht korrekt oder richtig. Einer der Lieblingsfehler der Deutschen ist es, "wo" statt "als" zu benutzen. Das macht es aber nicht richtiger, nur weil es immer häufiger so falsch benutzt wird...

Answer (score 4):

Deine Interpretation ist an sich richtig. Mittlerweile geht diese Feinheit im alltäglichen Gespräch allerdings unter. Häufig achten nur noch Firmen oder Profis auf den Unterschied. Beispielsweise kam bei der Bahn lange die Durchsage

> Wir entschuldigen uns für die Verspätung.

Bis sie korrigiert wurde:

> Wir bitten, die Verspätung zu entschuldigen.

Im alltäglichen Gespräch ist "Ich entschuldige mich dafür,..." akzeptiert statt der eigentlich richtigen Form "Ich bitte für ... um Entschuldigung". Die richtige Form wirkt aber nicht unnatürlich.

Comment: Ich fahre wohl zu oft Bahn, um diesen feinen Unterschied in diesem Beispiel richtig zu würdigen. Auch habe ich dabei kaum das Gefühl, das da irgend jemand irgendetwas Leid tut.

Comment: Entschuldigungsrituale gehören der Sphäre der Kultur an, und damit ist ein natürlich klingen gar nicht zu erwarten. Es hört sich aber richtig an wenn es richtig ausgesprochen wird.

Answer (score -1):

Für mich bleibt dennoch ein Restzweifel , dass der Mehrheit der tatsächliche Sinn bewusst ist und nicht eher wirklich eine leere Floskel. Ich bin geneigt zu glauben, dass dies in der Version (um Entschuldigung bitten) anders sein könnte. Eine Bitte zu stellen , hat eventuell doch etwas mehr Wirkung.