# What to say after someone sneezes?

Tags: idiom, culture

I've heard Germans saying:

> [Gesundheit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responses_to_sneezing)

But in a movie, someone sneezes and someone else saying:

> Heuschnupfen?

Is it polite? Is it colloquial? What else could I say when talking to someone and he/she sneezes, politely and formally?

Comment: Read this answer http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53955/what-is-an-alternative-to-bless-you-after-sneezing/53958#53958

Comment: Verhaltensregeln nach Knigge: http://www.brigitte.de/gesund/gesundheit/knigge-niesen-564462/

Comment: Related: [War "Gesundheit" immer nur ein Wort?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/war-gesundheit-immer-nur-ein-wort)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Saying "Gesundheit" is the polite way. Asking if the sneezing person has hay fever is rude, but ok if you have a close relation to that person (close friend).

Polite alternatives would be "Geht's wieder?" (Better now?) or "Wirst wohl krank?" (Getting ill?). This way you can show that you care for the person that sneezes.

I personally do not agree with the newly promoted rule to say nothing as this shows ignorance and being ill is nothing to be ashamed off.

Comment: Great answer, no further discussion.

Comment: I don't like the new rule either and even caught me paying more attention to always say “Gesundheit”...

Answer (score 12):

> "Gesundheit"

Yes, it is polite.

"Heuschnupfen?" in the movie it could be a question. The person sneezes and the other one asks if it's due to hay fever.

Comment: I see "Heuschnupfen?"  is a question, the point is one would ask if the person caught a cold when someone sneezes. I'm asking if it's a better response than "gesundheit".

Comment: @Gigili I think the "Heuschnupfen?" thing is quite special. I wouldn't ask anyone why s/he's sneezong :-)

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a (good) alternative.

The best you can say is simply *Gesundheit*. Some people add an additional pleasantry, like *und ein langes Leben* or whatever. But only a few people do so.

Some people, especially women, modify *Gesundheit* to something terrible like *Gesundi*, what is not an actual word, but is understood.

[Knigge](http://www.knigge.de/themen/kommunikation/niesen-3735.htm) advises to ignore when someone sneezes. Moreover, he consider an excuse as required

> Muss man selbst, oder aber eine andere Person in einem Raum niesen, ignoriert man dies als einen unerheblichen Zwischenfall. [...]
>
> Ein kurzes "Entschuldigung" ist durchaus angebracht, [...]

Regarding *Heuschnupfen*: As Oli said, it'is a question if the man/woman who is sneezing has hay fever. Assuming, the scene of the movie is at a time, when there are a lot of pollen.

Comment: *"Gesundi"*? Au weia...

Comment: @Jan Never heard that? I know, that expression is mental pain; just added for sake of completeness.

Comment: And I have one more, but attention please. It is more painful than *Gesundi* :D *Hatschi mein Schatzi* :D

Comment: AFAIK, the term "Gesundheit" was originally used as a sort of positive charm, to ward off the disease spread by the one who sneezes, which is why Knigge considers it a rude thing to say. The perception of the answer "Gesundheit!" to a sneeze has changed: it is now considered as wishing someone health, who apparently has a head cold or the flu.

Comment: I do not know who started this, that you should not say "Gesundheit" anymore, but all people I know do it. I have the feeling that some guys declared themselves as politeness experts (for what reason soever) and than started to tell everyone to skip it. Maybe some people are happy if they are told what to do ...

Comment: @JohnSmithers: I completely agree with you (on this issue only). As long as one would never say a "gesundheit" for each sneeze if someone sneezes a million times in a minute, saying nothing is not more polite than saying "gesundheit".

Comment: @John Smithers: I think Knigge started this ten or twenty years ago to comply with several other cultures. In 2008, however, Knigge revised their decision and now again explicitly "allows" saying "Gesundheit". But then, Knigge has several strange advices like how to serve asparagus that are at least arguable...

Comment: @OregonGhost: Knigge is overrated if you ask me. People who think they know better how to behave (especially if the majority looks like to disagree) are suspect at best. And "to comply with other cultures"? WTF? Have we really fallen that deep, that we are not allowed to have our own culture?

Comment: @John Smithers: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @OregonGhost: I thought Knigge died in 1796?

Comment: @celtschk: Yes, and...? Disney is also dead, yet releases movies every year...

Answer (score 4):

**Früher** sagte man in der Tat `Gesundheit`, aber heute ist es am höflichsten **gar nichts** zu sagen.

Den meisten Leuten ist es unangenehm, krank zu sein, und sie wünschen nicht daran erinnert oder bemitleidet zu werden.

Entweder die Leute bekommen nur ein Staubkorn in die Nase, dann ist ein einzelnes Niesen kein Symptom mangelnder Gesundheit, und der Wunsch unangemessen. Oder sie sind wahrhaft erkältet, dann sind sie mit dem Herauskramen des Taschentuches genug bestraft, und wünschen nicht alle zehn Minuten einer anderen Person gegenüber in ein

```
  Gesundheit
  Danke
```

Ritual zu verfallen. Höflicher ist es, so zu tun, als habe man nichts gemerkt.

Wenn man jedoch den ganzen Tag mit einer anderen Person im Büro sitzt, dann kann man durchaus einmal morgens `Gesundheit` wünschen, aber bitte nicht zu jedem Nieser, und nicht auf dem Flur, wo sich das schnell zum Spießrutenlauf auswächst, wenn aus sieben Büros ein aufmunterndes "Gesundheit" schallt, für das sich der Kranke dann jeweils artig bedanken soll.

Die Frage hat einen zweiten Aspekt, der offenbar von den Kommentatoren nicht bedacht wird, die eine einmalige Verständigung über die Konvention als zu umständlich ablehnen, und sich fürchten, als unhöflich zu gelten, wenn sie kein `Gesundheit` wünschen, und zwar ist dies die Interpretation, wenn andere Euch nicht `Gesundheit` wünschen. Betrachtet es dann zur Sicherheit als Versuch, besonders höflich zu sein, und nicht als mutwilligen Affront.

Die Situation ist übrigens ähnlich zum Phänomen des Mahlzeit-Sagens, schön illustriert durch [dieses Poltvideo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PAaqr9ZoZw).

Comment: This is correct. The politest thing is to say nothing at all. As a rule of thumb: "Don't comment any sounds of the body".

Comment: Doesn't the person get the impression that I don't care?

Comment: @Gigili: Maybe. For a random contact, you will not care so much about it. For people, you're acting with on a daily basis, you can clarify it once for all times. Ask for an agreement for the new habit which you heard of, and which sounds reasonable to you.

Comment: @userunknown: What about just saying "Gesundheit" when they sneeze instead of all of that agreements and clarifications?

Comment: I said: 'acting with on a daily basis' which means one convesation over 20 years instead of 1000 times "Gesundheit".

Comment: @userunknown You must be an engineer :-)

Comment: @Gigili: Ich habe einen weiteren Absatz angefügt, um die zweite Seite der Medaille zu beleuchten.

Comment: @userunknown: Danke schön.

Comment: @Gigili: Keine Ursache

Comment: @Gigili: Ich mach es umgedreht, ich sage den Leuten, mit denen ich länger im Kontakt stehe und mir Gesundheit wünschen, dass sie das nicht brauchen. Als Heuschnupfler wären die den halben Tag nur damit beschäftigt mir Gesundheit zu wünschen.

Answer (score 0):

In Austria (at least) you'll also hear "Zum Wohl" ("to your health").